# Every infinite finitely generated group $G$ has an infinite quotient with only finite proper quotients

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, finitely-generated, infinite-groups

I am trying to prove this statement:

> Every finitely generated group $G$ that is infinite has a normal subgroup $K$ such that $G/K$ is infinite and has only finite proper quotients.

This is a problem from a group theory work sheet. The problem text also suggests that the following lemma (due to Poincaré) should be used:

> All subgroups of finite index of a finitely generated group are also finitely generated.

I feel like the lemma suggests that some sort of induction should be used here, together with the third isomorphism theorem. I am having trouble seeing how we even need the condition that $G$ be finitely generated here, though. Here is my proof attempt, which does not use this property at all:

> If $G$ has only finite proper quotients, we are done. Therefore, let $G$ be a group with infinite proper quotients. We then have a nonempty set $L$ of normal subgroups $K$ of $G$ such that $G/K$ is infinite. Every chain in $L$ has an upper bound in $L$ (i.e. the union of all the elements in the chain), thus by Zorn's Lemma we have maximal elements of $L$. Let $K \in L$ be maximal.
>
> We know $G/K$ is infinite. If $G/K$ has only trivial normal subgroups ($1$, $G/K$ itself), we are done. Therefore let $M/K \lhd G/K$ be a nontrivial normal subgroup (we know that each normal subgroup of $G/K$ has this form). We then have $M \lhd G$ and $K < M$, therefore $M \notin L$, thus $G/M$ is finite. By the third isomorphism theorem,
> $$ G/M \cong (G/K)/(M/K),$$
> thus every proper quotient of $G/K$ is finite.

I must be missing something. Perhaps the union of chain elements might not actually be contained in $L$ is $G$ is not finitely generated, but I don't see why that would be the case.

Comment: How do you know that the union of a chain of subgroups in $L$ lies in $L$? How do you know that this union  has infinite index in $G$? There are groups that are not finitely generated (such as quasicyclic groups)  in which this condition fails.

Comment: How do you know $G/K$ is infinite?

Comment: @DerekHolt So as expected, that is where the error in the proof lies. Do you have a hint on how to prove that the union of a chain of subgroups does indeed lie in $L$ if $G$ is finitely generated?

Comment: By the way, it took me a while to figure out what were asking. You should say something like "I am trying to prove the statement in the title of this post".

Comment: Thank you, I will do that in the future.

Comment: Yes, if $G/K$ is finite then by your lemma $K$ is finitely generated, so each of its generators lies in one of the subgroups in the chain, so they all lie in the same subgroup in the chain, but then this must be equal to $K$, contradiction.

Comment: That is much more intuitive than I expected. Thank you very much!

Comment: The text of the post should rather not depend on the title (the title is an addition to the post, not part of the post). I edited accordingly.